# How does iOS perform Gmail SMTP authentication?

Tags: ios, email, authentication, google-oauth

I'm curious if anyone knows what specifically the iOS stock Mail app does to use OAuth2 (presumably) without ever prompting the user with a Google sign-in/authentication (I know that it prompts for the username/password via its own UI).  It seems like any documented method of obtaining an OAuth2 token for a user requires a Google sign-in experience (Google+ API) or re-directing to a Google URL to allow the user to authenticate and authorize the app.  However iOS Mail never does any of these things yet is still able to SMTP Authenticate (again presumably via OAuth2 - Gmail SMTP settings mentioning "Gmail client token" as the "Authentication" method)

I do not have 2-factor auth turned on and Mail never prompted me with a "Google" sign-in or re-direction - it just set everything up behind the scenes by utilizing my username and password.  Is there anyway for other apps to replicate this user experience if they have a username + password without going through a Google UI sign-in or URL?  Just curious... thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure the iOS Mail app just uses the standard [IMAP interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol).

Comment: Haven't looked much into this but is there any chance they are using xAuth? If Google offers this, it would be a way to authenticate users in your own custom interface.

Comment: abraham - this regarding how iOS authenticates to google's SMTP servers for sending mail (IMAP is for mail retrieval).  user3647894 - not sure about xAuth but I don't think so - I would need to look into it more.  I've been searching all over and have yet to figure out how they do it - my best guess is that Google is giving iOS' mail app some special privileges to allow their add account flow to act as a proxy for Google's own authentication and authorization.